bounties will probably increase interaction
chasing after bounties can not only be fun but quite rewarding. More posts are coming but bounties Drive a lot of interaction. adding these would be really great.

Bounties are added by members "investing" their own reputation. The one who places the bounty immediately loses the "invested" amount of reputation. And even if there are no useful answers after the seven days, the reputation will be gone and depending on the votes of others, the highest voted answer will either get 50% of the bounty value if the person placing the bounty doesn't award it, or the full value if it gets consciously awarded. I've placed bounties in the past. But I only place bounties on topics that interest me or help me. So this is nothing that can be somehow added ...

This is already implemented by the parent StackExchange network. Please see What is a bounty? How can I start one?.
If you have suggestions on how to improve it on the network level, please post on Meta.SE.
